# What does this mean: "Credit card balance within $2000 of card limit"?

Tags: semantics

I'm trying to create an alert on my credit card so that I get a text message when the total charges on my credit card go over $1000.

Let's say my credit card limit is $3000. If I set the alert to send me a text message when my credit card balance is within $2000 of the card limit, is this equivalent to saying that I will get an alert when my card balance is over $1000 in this case?

The wording is confusing for me for some reason, and I can't get over it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, within $2000 of a $3000 limit would be equivalent to a balance of over $1000.

There is a slight ambiguity on the edge case where a balance of exactly $1000 might, or might not, trigger the alert as *within* could potentially be interpreted to be "*this amount or less*" or "*strictly less than this amount*", although for your use case, it probably isn't terribly important.